# URL to "Team Site" page in edit mode

Tags: team-sites

I have a Team Site page and I want to retrieve an url of this page in an edit mode. The problem is that a url of this page in edit and display modes are the same. It doesn't change. How can I solve this problem? I have tried to use:

ControlMode=Edit and DisplayMode=Design

But it doesn't work with a Team Site.

Thank you!

Comment: No one? Please help me with that.

Answer (score 13):

add ?ToolPaneView=2&pagemode=edit to the end of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line at the end of your page URL.

```
?WikiPageMode=Edit&WikiMergeTarget=true
```